# "super ugly number" clarification

Tags: algorithm

**Write a program to find the nth super ugly number.
Super ugly numbers are positive numbers whose all prime factors are in the given prime list of size k. For example, [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 13, 14, 16, 19, 26, 28, 32] is the sequence of the first 12 super ugly numbers given primes = [2, 7, 13, 19] of size 4.**

I don't understand the question. That is what I need help/clarification on:

In the above statement, why are [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 13, 14, 16, 19, 26, 28, 32] the first 12 super ugly numbers? How is that related to the given input **primes = [2, 7, 13, 19]**

Comment: `[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 13, 14, 16, 19, 26, 28, 32]` all have a prime factor in your list of primes -> `[2, 7, 13, 19]`

Comment: Seems more of a math/puzzle question than a programming one.

Comment: @Vasan: Still better than most questions. ;)

Comment: please fix the tags, this isn't a java or a python programming problem.

Comment: @Srini what tags do you recommend for these clarification questions?

Comment: just algorithm should suffice IMHO. Using python or java would indicate that there is something related to either in the question

Answer (score 3):

```
2 -> 2
4 -> 2 * 2
7 -> 7
8 -> 2 * 2 * 2
13 -> 13
14 -> 2 * 7
16 -> 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
19 -> 19
26 -> 2 * 13
28 -> 2 * 2 * 7
32 -> 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
```

Not sure why 1 is on the list. ;)

Edit: The question statement says that 1 should always be a super ugly number.

Comment: @cppbeginner: Thanks! :) I didn't count it well. ;)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. The question statement says that 1 should be a super ugly number. Here is the link:https://leetcode.com/problems/super-ugly-number/description/

Comment: @dev74 since that's a note I would just assume you always count 1 for whatever silly reason

Answer (score 2):

You are given a list containing a selection of prime numbers : for example, `[2,7,13,19]`.

What you must do is take each natural integer (1, 2, ...), starting from 1, and calculate its prime factors. If all those prime factors belong to the list of "authorized" prime numbers given above, then the number is declared "super ugly".

For example, the prime factors of 14 are `[2, 7]`, which are all in the reference list (`[2,7,13,19]`). So, 14 is super ugly.

You job is to find the Nth super ugly number with that method.